# Write a MA(q) process to represent an AR(1)

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, moving-average-model

I have the following AR(1) process:
$$
Y_t = 4 + 0.2Y_{t-1} + a_t \qquad a_t \sim WN(0,1)
$$

The exercise asks to write the MA(q) process sufficient to represent the AR(1) model considered. The exercise assumes $Y_0 = 0$ and it asks to calculate to the third decimal place.

I got the following quantities:

- $E(Y_t) = \mu = 5$,
- $\gamma_0 = 1/0.96$
- $\gamma_1 = 0.2/0.96$
- $\rho_1 = \phi_1 = 0.2$

I was thinking to start writing:
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_1 & = a_1 \\
Y_2 & = \phi_1 Y_1 + a_2 = \phi_1 a_1 + a_2 \\
Y_3 & = \phi_1 Y_2 + a_3 = \phi^{2}_1 a_3 + \phi_1 a_2 + a_1 \\
\end{align*}
$$

But I would have risked finding myself with an MA($\infty$) process.

## **Update**

I have found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBYgDY7BkBc) that explains how to do.

For example, we define the process like into video: $Y_t = \delta + \theta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$. We apply the recursive substitution:
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_t & = \delta + \theta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \\
& = \delta + \theta (\delta + \theta Y_{t-2} + \epsilon_{t-1}) + \epsilon_t \\
& = \delta + \theta \delta + \theta^2 Y_{t-2} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \\
& = (1 + \theta) \delta + \theta^2 Y_{t-2} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \\
& = (1 + \theta) \delta + \theta^2 (\delta + \theta Y_{t-3} + \epsilon_{t-2}) + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \\
& = (1 + \theta + \theta^2) \delta + \theta^3 Y_{y-3} + \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \theta^2 \epsilon_{t-2} \\
& \vdots \\
& = (1 + \theta + \theta^2 + ... + \theta^{t-1}) \delta + \theta^t Y_0 + \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \theta^2 \epsilon_{t-2} + ... + \theta^{t-1} \epsilon_1 \\
& = \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} \theta^i \delta + \theta^t Y_0 + \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} \theta^i \epsilon_{t-i}
\end{align*}
$$

I try to apply it to my problem.

I know that $\delta = 4$, $\theta = 0.2$ and $Y_0 = 0$. Let's proceed:
$$
Y_t = \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i 4 + \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i \epsilon_{t-i}
$$

Since $0.2 < 1$ we can rewrite the first sum:
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_t & = \frac{4 (0.2^t - 1)}{0.2 - 1} + \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i \epsilon_{t-i} \\
& =  - \frac{4 (0.2^t - 1)}{0.8} + \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i \epsilon_{t-i} \\
& = - 5(0.2^t - 1) + \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i \epsilon_{t-i} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Finally:
$$
\begin{equation}
Y_t = - 5(0.2^t - 1) + \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i \epsilon_{t-i} \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
$$

where the first term I could define it like a constant while the second term is a stochastic trend that's a MA process.

Nevertheless, the exercise asks to calculate to the third decimal place. Where could I have gone wrong?

## **Update No. 2**

I gave it some thought and realized that the second term of (1) recalls the serie
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n (x - x_0)^n
$$

where $\epsilon_{t-i}$ plays the role of $a_n$ while $\theta^i$ plays the role of $(x-x_o)^n$. Besides, I try to solve. Sorry if I assume the series for $t < \infty$ but I want to try.

I manage the second term of (1) in the following way:
$$
\sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i \epsilon_{t-i} = \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i \cdot \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} \epsilon_{t-1} = \frac{0.2^t - 1}{0.2 - 1} \cdot \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} \epsilon_{t-1} = - \frac{0.2^t - 1}{0.8} \cdot \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} \epsilon_{t-1}
$$

I got the following
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_t & = - 5(0.2^t - 1) - \frac{0.2^t - 1}{0.8} \cdot \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} \epsilon_{t-1} \\
& = -(0.2^t - 1) \left[ 5 + \frac{1}{0.8} \cdot \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} \epsilon_{t-1} \right] \\
& = -(0.2^t - 1) \left[ 5 + 1.25 \cdot \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} \epsilon_{t-1} \right] \\
\end{align*}
$$

However, they only get one equation for genetic $t$, with which I cannot do calculations up to the third decimal place. Where do I go wrong? Sorry, but I'm trying some attempts to find a solution and it seems that I don't understand where go.

## **Update No.3: Final**

@whuber I have tried to use your hint, but I couldn't solve it.
However, I have found an other solution to the question.
Let $B$ the lag operator, hence:
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_t & = 4 + 0.2Y_{t-1} + a_t \\
Y_t - 0.2Y_{t-1} & = 4 + a_t \\
Y_t (1 - 0.2B) & = 4 + a_t \\
Y_t & = (1 - 0.2B)^{-1} (4 + a_t) \\
& = \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} 0.2^i B^i (4 + a_t) = \sum^{t-1}_{i=0} (0.2B)^i (4 + a_t) \\
\end{align*}
$$

I develop the sum:
$$
\sum^{t-1}_{i=0} (0.2B)^i= 1 + 0.2B + 0.2^2 B^2 + 0.2^3 B^3 + ...
$$

I write $0.2=2/10$ and I apply this sum to the term $(4 + a_t)$:
$$
(4 + a_t) + \frac{2B(4 + a_t)}{10} + \frac{4B^2(4 + a_t)}{100} + \frac{8B^3(4 + a_t)}{1000} + ...
$$

The lag operator of a constant is a constant: $Ba = a$, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, while $B^k Y_t = Y_{t-k}$. Hence:
$$
(4 + a_t) + \frac{2(4 + a_{t-1})}{10} + \frac{4(4 + a_{t-2})}{100} + \frac{8(4 + a_{t-3})}{1000} + ...
$$

Finally, I aprox the sum to the third sum (with $4 + a_t = \phi^{*}$):
$$
Y_t \approx \phi^{*} + \frac{2(4 + a_{t-1})}{10} + \frac{4(4 + a_{t-2})}{100} + \frac{8(4 + a_{t-3})}{1000}
$$

Comment: @utobi I have fixed adding the information.

Comment: Hint: work with the series $y_t - 4/(1-0.2) = y_t - 5$ and notice how the recurrence relation no longer involves an additive constant.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, I will immediately try to apply your contribution